# PnP Powershell: Add-PnPGroupMemeber chooses the wrong site to add group memeber

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have several SharePoint Online sites, like
sites/mysite1
sites/mysite2
sites/mysite3
I am the owner of all these sites.

I am trying to add a user to the visitors group of mysite1:

```
 $SiteUrl = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite1"
 $destinationConnection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Interactive -ReturnConnection
 $group = Get-PnPGroup -Connection $destinationConnection -AssociatedVisitorGroup
 Add-PnPGroupMember -LoginName "tester@abc.com" -Group $group
```

I can see the $group returns the CORRECT group object. But the Add-PnPGroupMember adds the user to the visitors group of mysite3 (or the last site created).

Comment: Try passing the connection as well. `Add-PnPGroupMember -LoginName "tester@abc.com" -Group $group -Connection $destinationConnection`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment. It appears the connection is required for subsites, as it was for `Get-PnpGroup`

```
Add-PnPGroupMember -LoginName "tester@abc.com" -Group $group -Connection $destinationConnection
```

[Add-PnPGroupMember](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPGroupMember.html)